# possible error in VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a column:

```
C1: 0:8:35 
C2: 0:8:40 
C3: 0:8:45 
and so on.
```

D1: 0:8:40

I'm trying this :

VLOOKUP(C2,C1..C30,1,TRUE) returns: 0:8:40

(1 - we have one column)
(TRUE - range lookup - should give the closest number in ascending order !

When I try 
VLOOKUP(D1,c1..c30,1,TRUE) returns 0:8:35

Altough C2 and D1 have the exact same value
(if(c2=d1, "ok", "not ok") returns OK.

I am using range lookup so I can find also 0:8:36 ect...

Any ideas ?

IMPORTANT EDIT: 
it works ok when you enter the numbers in the search column.
if you create the list using 0:8:35 and each next cell as the previous + 0:0:05 - than the error occurs !!
checked the evaluation of the calculation and in both case it's evaluates to the same number, but yields different results !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Trunc(c1,16) fix it.....
although they are exactly the same only after trunc it works.

Answer (score 1):

Always use false instead of true.

False gets you the exact match.
True gets you similar matches.

Comment: In this case I needed a range match and not exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the 'format' of c1 into D1 and see if that helps.

Comment: it didn't help. it is a bug, but I've found a solution.